# Specific number of fields based on the difference of two date fields

Tags: splistitem

Number of fields = DateField2-DateField1
Generate Number of fields based on the difference of those two fields. 
Possible? 
Sharepoint 2010 List

Overview:
I'm working on a financial project tracking system that has start and end dates for a respective project. Is it possible generate number of fields based on the difference of start and end years? Say start year 2012 and end year 2016. Thus generate four fields. 
Would it be jquery? Calculated fields? Or any other pointer to a better solution would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: You can do almost anything with jQuery but the question is more how you plan on using and storing the data it collects.  Are these new fields supposed to be unique fields in a list or some concatenated value that is parsed later?

Comment: Yes. Those fields would have unique values (number fields). I.E. Above example would create four number fields:Requested Budget Year 1, Year 2, Year 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create new fields per list item so in order to do what you are suggesting, you would have to either create a list that contains the maximum number of fields that can be needed and only use up to the number specified, or create new lists for each request with the number of fields needed for that request.

Another possible option would be to create a new list item for each of the possible values, the project key and the associated value.  This would make your data vertical rather than horizontal and would complicate data entry and reporting but it would support what you are attempting to do.

Comment: I guess I'll go with jquery and hide the fields. And show only the number of fields based on the difference of date fields.